# ui-select-header-group-selectable directive on ui-select-choice does not work

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-select

`ui-select-header-group-selectable` in `ui-select-choices` makes the headers clickable, so you can select all the items in a group.

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: After bit of research, I found the answer myself. The answer is 'Yes', but the feature though documented, but not yet available, which is bit misleading. Very useful feature, hopefully it will be available soon.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the select.js for my project. I am not keeping real checkboxes, but using glyphicons.

[example-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J1uE.png)

https://github.com/maheshparlapalli/modified-ui-select-js-for-group-wise-check-boxes

search for 'toggleAllGroupSelected' in select.js, which is newly added function.

You will find the usage of 'toggleAllGroupSelected' in multiple places. Add this code to your select.js

Comment: Sorry, i don't know extending module directive. So i edited directly in select.js